# VBA - ContentControlOnEnter is affecting all my Controls, not just the one specified

Tags: vba, ms-word

I've set up a fillable form for courses. I'm trying to have the course end-date automatically populate depending on the course chosen and the start-date.

Instead of being triggered on entering the 'Endate' control, it triggers on entering all the controls which throws repeated runtime errors. I'd be willing to have the field populate when clicked, but that doesn't seem to be an option.

```
Private Sub Document_ContentControlOnEnter(ByVal Endate As ContentControl)

'Declare variable names to deal with the content control data
Dim SD As ContentControl
Dim TC As ContentControl
Dim TC1 As ContentControl
Dim ED As ContentControl
Dim NewDate

'Connect each variable name to its content control
Set TC = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("Training").Item(1)
Set SD = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("Stardate").Item(1)
Set ED = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("Endate").Item(1)
'For some reason, twice removed from the source works better
Set TC1 = TC

    If SD.Range.Text <> "Click to enter a date" Then
    NewDate = DateValue(SD.Range.Text)

'Look at Training Content Control - what was selected.
'If one of the two longer courses is picked, add 2 days to the start date
'and use that as the end date. Otherwise just add one day.
    Select Case TC1.Range.Text
        Case "Basic Skills"
            ED.Range.Text = Format((NewDate + 2), "MMM d, yyyy")
        Case "Caseworker"
            ED.Range.Text = Format((NewDate + 2), "MMM d, yyyy")
        Case Else
            ED.Range.Text = Format((NewDate + 1), "MMM d, yyyy")
    End Select
    End If

'Once we're done, re-set the variables for the next round. This does not change
'the content of the form.
    Set TC = Nothing
    Set SD = Nothing
    Set ED = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: [The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.contentcontrolonenter) on this isn't horribly clear, but it does say that it fires when the control is "entered".  I'm guessing that when you use `SelectContentControlsByTag`, you are "entering" the control by selecting it. I'd try enumerating the [`Document.ContentControls`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.contentcontrols) collection to find the  controls instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you see the described behavior

> Instead of being triggered on entering the 'Endate' control, it
>   triggers on entering all the controls

is due to a design decision by Microsoft for the content controls contained in a document. There is a single event for each event type that all content controls will trigger. The means, if code is specific to one or a few content controls, the content control that triggers the event needs to be evaluated and the code branched as required.

Notice the event signature passes the argument `ByVal ContentControl As ContentControl`. This is the content control that triggers the event. So giving this argument the name of a particular content control is not an optimal approach - it could be any content control.

I'm modified the first part of the code to illustrate how it can be structured to test which content control has triggered the event:

```
Private Sub Document_ContentControlOnEnter(ByVal cc As ContentControl)

'Declare variable names to deal with the content control data
Dim SD As ContentControl
Dim TC As ContentControl
Dim TC1 As ContentControl
Dim ED As ContentControl
Dim NewDate

If cc.Tag = "EndDate" Then
  'Connect each variable name to its content control
  Set TC = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("Training").Item(1)
  Set SD = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("Stardate").Item(1)
  Set ED = cc 
  'Do other things, here
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It works perfectly now. Thank you so much! Happy Monday!

Answer (score 0):

What i see based on the name of the event is that whenever you enter a control, it passes the enddate control to the code. Basically, just check and see if the enddate has a value before going on and doing the rest of it.

```
Private Sub Document_ContentControlOnEnter(ByVal Endate As ContentControl)
If len(Endate.Range.Text) > 0 then
    'Declare variable names to deal with the content control data
    Dim SD As ContentControl
    Dim TC As ContentControl
    Dim TC1 As ContentControl
    Dim ED As ContentControl
    Dim NewDate

    'Connect each variable name to its content control
    Set TC = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("Training").Item(1)
    Set SD = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("Stardate").Item(1)
    Set ED = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("Endate").Item(1)
    'For some reason, twice removed from the source works better
    Set TC1 = TC

        If SD.Range.Text <> "Click to enter a date" Then
        NewDate = DateValue(SD.Range.Text)

    'Look at Training Content Control - what was selected.
    'If one of the two longer courses is picked, add 2 days to the start date
    'and use that as the end date. Otherwise just add one day.
        Select Case TC1.Range.Text
            Case "Basic Skills"
                ED.Range.Text = Format((NewDate + 2), "MMM d, yyyy")
            Case "Caseworker"
                ED.Range.Text = Format((NewDate + 2), "MMM d, yyyy")
            Case Else
                ED.Range.Text = Format((NewDate + 1), "MMM d, yyyy")
        End Select
        End If

    'Once we're done, re-set the variables for the next round. This does not change
    'the content of the form.
        Set TC = Nothing
        Set SD = Nothing
        Set ED = Nothing
end if
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your speedy response and the suggested test. I entered in the two required pieces of data and ran the debug. It turns out ED.Range.Text in the Select block contains <Object variable or With block variable not set>. Stranger yet, when I returned to the document, the correct date appeared in the form (?!?).

Comment: That is strange, My focus is Access based VBA so, I'm going to have to do a little bit of poking to see if i can figure anything else out.

Comment: I get a method error when I enter the code lines you offered. That error appears when I try to select the course and again when I pick the start date. My understanding of the various help documents I found was that by stating the name of the contentcontrol in the sub line, that should be the only contentcontrol considered when running it.  Apparently not. I appreciate all your assistance. :-)

Comment: OK - I altered your code to If len(Endate.Range.Text) = 0 Then (etc.) and it stopped crashing on the other contentcontrols, but did not return an end date in that field. So half the issue solved I guess. LOL.

Comment: Yeah, back in Access land, all of the textbox controls use .value, and you only mess with the .text property in things like keypress events. i didn't see that, sorry.